# what is the usage of CIDR notation route rule in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have created a VPC and internet gate way. And attached internet gateway to the vpc. Create two subnets one is public subnet and another is private subnet. And created a route table to route the traffic. In route table added a route rule 0.0.0.0/0 to IGW(internet gatway). To test this I launch a EC2 instance in public subnet. I have generated a public IP address example : (554.6.8.24). Using that IP address do ssh and I am connecting from local machine to EC2 instance.

My question is I am connecting to the EC2 instance from my local machine using public IP. What is the point of adding route rule in 0.0.0.0/0 to IGW(internet gatway) in route table?. With out route rule can I connect to Ec2?

Comment: Try it out. Also try out connecting from the instance to anywhere else on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an Internet Gateway is *not* present in an Amazon VPC, then **that VPC has no connection to the Internet**. This can be very useful for creating private networks.

If you want to connect a VPC to the Internet, then you need to:

- Create an **Internet Gateway** for that VPC
- Create a **Route Table** that sends traffic to the Internet Gateway
- Attach the Route Table to a **Subnet** (thereby making that subnet a Public Subnet since it routes to the Internet Gateway)
- Put **resources** inside the Public Subnet (eg EC2 instances)

In contrast, **Private subnets do not have a Route Table entry that points to an Internet Gateway**. Therefore, those subnets cannot access the Internet. This is an added layer of security to prevent access to private resources.

The **only difference between a Public Subnet and a Private Subnet** is having the Route Table entry that points to an Internet Gateway. Without that entry, a subnet will remain private.

Comment: I am connecting to public subnet using public IP address and I am not connecting to internet from Ec2 instance .My question is why subnet needs 0.0.0.0/0 to IGW(internet gatway) route table entry to connect to internet.

Comment: The above configurations are also required for INBOUND traffic. If you remove any of them (eg do not use the Route Table), then the instance will not be accessible from the Internets. The Route Table works both ways.

Comment: thanks John Rotenstein I understood now